# Can't see stderr when running via launchd

Tags: python, plist, stderr, launchd

I am running a python program using launchd.  In my plist file I have set it up to redirect stdout and stderr to files that I am closely monitoring.  The stdout file is getting the output as expected, but the stderr is not.  (It was working yesterday, though).  Here is my plist file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>ddd.intern.runner</string>
    <key>LaunchOnlyOnce</key>
    <false/>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Users/Jon/dev/vpe/bin/python</string>
        <string>/Users/Jon/dev/intern/ddd_runner.py</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <false/>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/Users/Jon/dev/intern/ddd.stderr</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/Users/Jon/dev/intern/ddd.stdout</string>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>300</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

How can I debug this?

Comment: Have the file permissions been changed?  Are you getting an error, or is your stderr file simply not being written to?

Comment: Are there any messages in the Console? Are you sure the script is getting errors that need to be reported to stderr?